# Understanding how to use arg/3 and univ/2 in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this database in Prolog and I'm trying to return what Henry owns and who owns a car and a truck. I've tried everything I can think of to return what Henry owns and can't find a solution. I know how to return who owns a car or a truck individually with ?- owns(X,car(*,*,_))., but not at the same time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
owns(bill, car(ford, mustang, 1964)).
owns(sue, car(pontiac, gto, 1967)).
owns(george, car(honda, civic, 2013)).
owns(betty, truck(ford, f150, 2013)).
owns(henry, motorcycle(honda, goldwing, 2010)).
```

Comment: How about `findall/3`? Like this; `findall(Owner, owns(Owner, car(_, _, _)), Owners).`

Comment: `?- owns(henry, X).` -- now `X` is what `henry` `owns`.

Answer (score 4):

Prolog has a relational data model, but allows recursive terms instead of atomics only, like SQL, and doesn't give names to 'columns'. Loosely:

```
╒═════════════╤═════════════╕
│ SQL         │ Prolog      │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ table       │ predicate   │
│ record      │ clause      │
│ table name  │ functor     │
│ column      │ argument    │
╘═════════════╧═════════════╛
```

So, knowledge about attributes position is required. Conventionally, we can associate attribute' names in functors:

```
% get an owner of any kind listed
kinds_owner(Kinds, Owner) :- 
  owns(Owner, Object), Object =.. [Kind|_], member(Kind, Kinds).

% get owners of any kind listed
kinds_owners(Kinds, Owners) :- 
  setof(Owner, kinds_owner(Kinds, Owner), Owners).

?- kinds_owner([truck,motorcycle],X).
X = betty ;
X = henry.

?- kinds_owners([truck,motorcycle],Xs).
Xs = [betty, henry].
```

Comment: ┼1 for this nice table!

Comment: @CapelliC where is the limit of DB of prolog ? and if not, what the elegant way among include an SQL database  or use the internal DB?

Comment: @AnsPiter: limit: it's in memory... the most elegant interface... I would say [datalog](http://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/fernan/DES/), but it's an actual language itself, so a lot to learn...